# Cannot finish enchantment

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I want to enchant my elven gilded armor (flawless) with increased carrying capacity with a filled black soul gem, but it won't let me finish it.

Answer (score 4):

You are trying a combination that is not possible.
According to [this table](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Enchanting_Effects) you cannot apply a Carry Weight enchantment on chest armor. You can apply it to boots, gauntlets/gloves, rings and necklaces.
Either try a different piece of equipment or a different enchantment.

After selecting the armor, compatible enchantments should be highlighted.